# Change the Excel date input format?

Tags: excel, date

I've been struggling with Excel (2016) date formats. I know how to change display formats for dates and cells but the problem I have is the input format for dates. If I input a date as "DD.MM" or "DD.MM.YYYY" it does recognize it as a date but if I input the date as "DD.MM." (with the second dot after the month), Excel does not recognize it as a date anymore. The column in question is formatted as short date.

Is there anything that can be done or is this by-design? If so, it seems really strange as at least in my country it's the official way to write the date containing that second dot after the month number when there is no year included in the date.

I've been searching and Googling for solution but couldn't find anything on this really. I appreciate all comments and help regarding this question!

**SUMMARY/TL;DR:**

- Excel version is 2016, country is Finland and language is finnish
- Excel accepts/recognizes these as dates: 12.5 or 30.8
- Excel does NOT accept/recognize these as dates: 12.5. or 30.8.
- The column in question is formatted as short date
- The dot after the month seems to be screwing things up
- Why is this happening? Can anything be done?

Kind regards,
Tenttu

Comment: Why the minus on this question? Insted of clicking the down arrow it would be more helpful to ask for more info or let me know what the problem is, so that I could make corrections if needed.

Comment: I would guess that the Minus is because there is too much text and it is hard to understand at once.

Comment: What is your country and what language is your excel in?

Comment: My country is Finland and the language is finnish. Thank you for your comment, I will try to clear up my question with a summary.

Comment: So the input doesn't work but you can still change the format to let Excel recognize it is a date afterwards correct?

Comment: @Pierre44 I have the column formatted as short date and if I input a date into that column as "30.8" it will change into the full date (30.8.2018) but if I input "30.8." instead, it stays like that and Excel won't process it as a date at all. So the dot after the month screws things up somehow. That is strange because in Finland it's the official way of writing the date without year.

Comment: So.. you need a solution that can make excel 'take' "DD.MM." as a valid date input right? or you just need the (how-it-happens) explanation ?

Comment: I have the same problem, I format date as the UK so it's been displayed correctly. However excel still insists that I enter date in the US format: mm/dd/yyyy regardless that display format is dd/mm/yyyy. Why downwoting this question, it's good one !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is/was by design. *(Funny enough, my Excel won't allow dots, only dashes (-), so I couldn't even test if "15.8" works)*

So, there's a slight chance that the ***language of Excel*** (the defaults of time (24 hours or AM/PM), dates (MM/DD or DD/MM), decimals (comma or dot) etc.) wouldn't allow the dot at after the month. [Here's an example](https://superuser.com/questions/1367021/excel-date-format-with-abbreviated-month-without-the-dot) of a user that has that dot, and wants to get rid of it. So, your system language is a good candidate for why this wouldn't work for you.

However, I realize that the example linked above don't feature a date with a dot at the end. Which could suggest it is rather by design. For example, if I add a dot to a valid date or time, it will result in some `#VALUE!`-error. And that's because of how Excel is programmed to convert text to a date - and remember, dates are actually just really large numbers. So, adding a dot at the end makes that conversion "impossible". We might think it's as easy as to remove a dot, but in programming, we need to program that explicitly to do that, and I'm leaning towards there is no such operation done during text to date conversion (certainly not on my system, as I get `#VALUE!`).

One work-around is to strip the ending dot from the date to make it a valid date. So, you can import sheets with dates with dots at the end, then strip them away, and you'll be good to go!